# how to display the links in tabs in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need to display the a.php,b.php,c.php in the tabs tab2,tab3,tab4 respectively i have written the following code but the links a.php,b.php,c.php is not displaying in the tabs tab2,tab3,tab4 respectively instead of that if i click on the tab2 it redirects to the a.php page but i need to display in a tab manner in which if i click the tab2 it should display the a.php in the tab2 respectively what should i change to display the links on the tab ? kindly help me Thanks in advance

```
    <script >
    $('#tab2').load('a.php');
    $('#tab3').load('b.php');
    $('#tab4').load('c.php');
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="tabbable" style="margin-bottom: 18px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Request Audit</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Status</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Help</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                  <p>Placeholder 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                  <p>Placeholder 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                  <p>Placeholder 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                  <p>Placeholder</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need to include jquery , and wrap your code in  $(document).ready();

Comment: i have inserted this <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> for jquery and  i have added $(document).ready(); but still it is not working

Comment: checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/

Comment: i need to display the content in a.php,b.php ,c.php in the tab tab2 should contain content in the a.php like that how can i do this ??

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is with the JQuery and not with the data you are trying to load? The [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on .load() includes details of how to check for errors loading the content. The code you have looks fine - I would say the issue is far more likely to be with what you are trying to load.

Comment: Still dont have a solution? :o

Comment: nope still didnt find

Answer (score 1):

You can change the href link by using    **$("#tab1").attr("href", "#a.php");**

```js
$(function(){
  $("#tab1").attr("href", "#a");
  $("#tab2").attr("href", "#b");
  $("#tab3").attr("href", "#c");
  $("#tab4").attr("href", "#d");
   
  
  
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  

<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a id="tab1" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab2" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab3" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab4" href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="a" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tesing a.php </p>
        </div>
        <div id="b" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tesing b.php </p>
        
        </div>
        <div id="c" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tesing c.php  </p>
        </div>
        <div id="d" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tesing d.php </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is not working please let me know. you can change the href link what ever you want to give u can give.

Comment: check this once you want like this?

Comment: i have changed everything but it is not working the content in the a.php,b.php,c.php is not displaying

Comment: can you check now @ArunKumaresh

Comment: Are you going to just print the markup or a dynamic content?

Comment: need to display the content in the a.php,b.php,c.php in the respective tabs tab2,tab3,tab4 the files may contain dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Fix is to put your script code into a document ready function as below

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
      $('#tab2').load('a.php');
      $('#tab3').load('b.php');
      $('#tab4').load('c.php');
});
</script>
```

**Alternate Solution**
Alternatively, you can workout as below.
As you are loading jquery from a third party domain, this document ready statements are executed first asynchronously. So download the jquery.min.js and load it from your local.

Comment: @ArunKumaresh  I figured out what goes wrong. I updated my answer. Try either one of the solution as you want. first one is to replace document.ready with window load. second one is to load jquery.min.js from your local

Comment: @ArunKumaresh Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: no error when i click the tab nothing is displaying only empty screen is displaying @thanga

Comment: Are you able to run your php files separately in your browser  like http://localhost/a.php

Comment: yup php files running fine in localhost but it is not displaying in the tab

Comment: In that case, Path of the PHP files must be a problem. As per your code, the current file where you have this code and a.php,b.php,c.php files must be in the same directory. Is it correct ?

Comment: everything is in the same directory only

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/xEyCgCo.png   this is what i see in my local.  You can check you are getting files loaded in console